# PostgreSQL: Accessing fields of record types

Tags: postgresql, field, record

I have a function that returns a record

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION atPeriod(
    IN segment segmentST,
    IN period period,
    OUT n integer,
    OUT s segmentST,
    OUT p pointST)
  RETURNS record AS
'$libdir/Hermes', 'atPeriodSegmentSTV1'
  LANGUAGE c STABLE STRICT
  COST 1;
```

I call that function in another function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distance(seg1 segmentST, seg2 segmentST) RETURNS realTS AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    projseg1 record;
    projseg2 record;
BEGIN
    SELECT atPeriod(seg1,p) INTO projseg1; 
    SELECT atPeriod(seg2,p) INTO projseg2; 
    IF (projseg1).n = 2 AND (projseg2).n = 2 THEN
        ...
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute the second function I receive the error

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: record "projseg1" has no field "n"
SQL state: 42703
```

If instead I call the first function in a SQL statement

```
WITH Rec AS (
select 2 as seg_id, atPeriod(SegmentST(
pointst('2012-01-01 08:00:00', 1, 2),
pointst('2012-01-01 08:02:00', 2, 2)),
period('2012-01-01 08:00:00', '2012-01-01 08:01:00')
) as seg
)
Select (seg).n from rec
```

I receive the value 2 and no error.

Any hint how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Translate this `n'a pas pu identifier la colonne « n » dans le type de données de l'enregistrement`

Comment: @vivek It's actually rather handy to have errors in the original language (though of course English summaries are nice). The original message can be grepped for in the source code after doing a quick lookup in the translation files to get the English message template it came from. A translation usually cannot be.

Comment: @CraigRinger I don't understand which Language is that if I knew then I can use translator, In this case only OP or the one who can read that language only understand what it means :)

Comment: @vivek I mean you can use the PostgreSQL sources, without needing to know anything except the text. e.g. `git grep -B 4 -A 4 'pas pu identifier la colonne'` shows that it's the message-template `could not identify column \"%s\" in record data type` from `parser/parse_expr.c:407`

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for notifying me :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because your `projseg1` & `projseg2` variables are `record`s, so they'll [automatically configure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) themselves to the row type of the query result columns (which is exactly `row(row(n, s, p))` but not, what you want: `row(n, s, p)`).

To select only the row (which is not encapsulated into another row), you should use:

```
SELECT * INTO projseg1 FROM atPeriod(seg1, p);
-- or:
projseg2 := atPeriod(seg2, p);
```